# Angular: when clicking on the picture, the subsequent comments do not show up

Tags: angular, typescript

It is frustrating that the following code doesn't work properly. This is the code I directly copy and paste from an online course from which I learn Angular. 
The purpose of the code is that when I click on the picture, a card view and subsequent comments will show up. But when I click on the picture, nothing appears. It seems so strange, and yet there are no errors elsewhere.

As can be seen from the code, there is a "shared" folder in which I store all my information. If anyone needs them, I can copy and paste them here.

`menu.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Dish } from '../shared/dish'
import { DISHES } from '../shared/dishes'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.scss']
})

export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

  dishes: Dish[] = DISHES;

  selectedDish : Dish;

  onSelect( dish : Dish ) {
    this.selectedDish = dish;
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

`dishdetail.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Dish } from '../shared/dish'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dishdetail',
  templateUrl: './dishdetail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dishdetail.component.scss']
})
export class DishdetailComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  dish: Dish

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

`dishdetail.component.html`:

```
<div class="container"
    fxLayout="row"
    fxLayout.sm="column"
    fxLayout.xs="column"
    fxLayoutAlign.gt-md="space-around center"
    fxLayoutGap="10px" 
    fxLayoutGap.xs="0">

    <div fxFlex="40" *ngIf="dish">
      <mat-card>
        <mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-title>
            <h3>{{dish.name | uppercase}}</h3>
          </mat-card-title>
        </mat-card-header>
        <img mat-card-image src={{dish.image}} alt={{dish.name}}>
        <mat-card-content>
          <p>{{dish.description}}
          </p>
        </mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-actions>
          <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
          <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
        </mat-card-actions>
      </mat-card>

    </div>

    <div fxFlex="40" *ngIf="dish">
        <mat-list>
          <h3>Comments</h3>
            <mat-list-item *ngFor="let comment of dish.comments">
              <style> .mat-list-item {
                  min-height: 80px;
              }</style>
              <p matline>
              <span>{{comment.comment}}<br></span>
              <span>{{comment.rating}} Stars<br></span>
              <span>-- {{comment.author}} {{comment.date | date}}</span>
              </p>
          </mat-list-item>
        </mat-list>
    </div>

</div>
```

`menu.component.html`:

```
<div class="container"
     fxLayout="column"
     fxLayoutGap="10px">

  <div fxFlex>
    <div>
      <h3>Menu</h3>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div fxFlex>
    <mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="200px">
      <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let dish of dishes" (click) = "onSelect(dish)">
        <img height="200px" src={{dish.image}} alt={{dish.name}}>
        <mat-grid-tile-footer>
          <h1>{{dish.name | uppercase}}</h1>
        </mat-grid-tile-footer>
      </mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>
  </div>

  <app-dishdetail [dish] = "SelectedDish"></app-dishdetail>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One little thing I see is this:

```
selectedDish : Dish;
```

And then this:

```
<app-dishdetail [dish] = "SelectedDish"></app-dishdetail>
```

Angular is case sensitive. So it should be:

```
<app-dishdetail [dish] = "selectedDish"></app-dishdetail>
```

With a lower case "s"